# How to add previous output values as input values in python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 3 dataFrames a,b, and c.I want to calculate the sum of a+b+previous output(c).

```
a=pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4])
b=pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4])
c=pd.DataFrame([])
c=c.append(a+b+c.shift(1))
```

Here I have already to dataframes a and b ,then i created a new dataframe c for saving output of the calculation."c.shift(1) means the previous output.

It shows error.How it is possible??

Comment: It would be helpful if you could give an example of what output you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appending will only work in a loop and will not return a value so you could do it but your computation can be reduced to cumsum in this case:

```
a=pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4])
b=pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4])
c=(a+b).cumsum()
```